# Sencha Touch app, doesn't want to load on device

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch

I try to run Sencha Touch hello [world app](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/first_app) on Android phone and emulator, but there is just  tree dots at the middle of the screen. It doesn't want to load `launch` function.
When I try to run it in browser it works pretty fine.

I'm new with Sencha, and I followed all instructions from documentation to create My first app, also there is no errors in log, but my app is just blocked at loading screen!

Comment: The link that you have provided, contains some comments at the bottom. Please have a look at it. I think you are not the only person who is having this problem.

Comment: In the comments I just found developers with same problem, but there is no solution.
What I'm doing for now is `sencha app build native` , and than upload MyApp.apk file to phone. I believe that problem is in `.sencha/app/microloader/production.js` file invoked from index.html